# Wallet for moving BCHN out of Abra

Tags: bitcoin-cash

I have some BCHN in Abra and I need to move it to a different wallet.  So far, the Abra app tells me that the wallet I am trying to move to is not a BCHN wallet.  I think have tried all of the major wallets. Are there any wallets that Abra will recognize as a BCHN wallet, or should I just abandon those coins?

Comment: What is Abra? Can you link that? I think this is offtopic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is off topic, but I think I can help you:

1. Locate a vanity addresses generator. Maybe vanitygen-plus is good enough for your case?
2. Generate some Bitcoin [legacy] addresses and their corresponding private keys using the vanity generator.
3. Use blockchair to get the corresponding bcash addresses for those legacy addresses.

   3.1 Optionally use the ecash address translator (or maybe blockchair as well, if it still supports ecash) to get the corresponding ecash addresses for those bcash addresses.
4. If your BCHN wallet service doesn't like legacy addresses obtained in 2, feed it the bcash addresses obtained in 3. At least one group should be a valid withdraw destination on any service.
5. Probe the BCHA chain. If for some reason the BCHN transactions corresponding to your withdrawals get replayed on BCHA (likely won't happen at this point), you are covered by step 3.1.

Happy shitcoining!